# Unless condition_A then condition_b

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In a problem based on selection of a team from the set of players ={R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}, one the constraints is

> Unless T and U are selected then V is selected.

I would like to know the propositional logic statement for this.

I understand "cond_A unless cond_B" logic but what does

> Unless A then B mean?

Furthermore, in the specific scenario can T,U,V all be seleceted in the team?

Comment: "Unless A then B" means the same thing as "B unless A". Both are equivalent to "A or B". "Unless" isn't standard terminology, though, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Unless A then B means that B will be selected in ALL those cases where A is not selected, i.e.

NOT(A) => B

Comment: So I can have both B evaluate to True and A evaluate to True  i.e. T,U and V can be selected together? But I can form a team with all the three T,U,V out of the team?

Comment: Nope, you can’t. You can have any of these selections: (T,U) (T,V) (U,V) but not (T,U,V). And if neither of T and U is selected, then V has to be there.